# why it says loc is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

hello am trying to save the two locations of the ids into an array by calling a function which is outside the loop. the problem is that it gives me an error saying that loc is not a function. Does anyone know where is the problem?

```
var geocoder;
var map, x, y;
var loc = [];
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
//    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
//  var user='33936357';
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=33936357,606020001&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var screen_name = item.screen_name;
        var img = item.profile_image_url;
        var location = item.location;
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: location
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var x = response[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    y = response[0].geometry.location.lng();
                loc(x, y);

            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        }); //GEOCODER.GEOCODE
    });

    function loc(x, y) {
        loc.push({
            latitude: x,
            longitude: y
        });
    }
    console.log(loc); //$.EACH
}); //.GETJSON
} //CODEADDRESS
```

Comment: You appear to have invalidated the question by amending the code to remove the problem. Please reinstate the incorrect code so the answers make sense (and then accept the answer which helped you).

Answer (score 0):

You declared an array named `loc`. Use a different name for the array variable, or change the function name.

Your problem is like below:

```
​var foo = [];
function foo() {
  foo.push(1);    
}
foo(); // here foo is the array []
```

Answer (score 0):

Here loc is an array:

```
var loc=[];
```

Here loc is a function:

```
function loc(x,y){loc.push({latitude:x,longitude:y});}
```

On which line does your debugger report the error?

Comment: on this line location(x,y); where am calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Within the `$.each()` callback function you create a local variable:

```
var location = item.location;
```

...which has the same name as the function `location()` declared *outside* the `$.each()`. By re-using the name the inner variable "masks" the outer function.

So you get the error about it not being a function because within the scope of that callback `location` refers to the local variable which is not a function.

Simply change the name of the variable or the function.

Comment: i changed the name of the variable but now it gives me an empty array.it doesnt save anything

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the `geocoder.geocode()` function is asynchronous so it's calling your callback to add items to the array _after_ you run the `console.log(loc)` statement. (You could confirm this by putting a `console.log(x)` inside the `location()` function.)

Comment: Well fix the variable/function name issues first - now that you've changed the question code back it's essentially the same problem but with the `loc` array and `loc()` function as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: i cant fix the code again i had to put it in first state when i question the problem,but the variables I changed over my code and am still getting an empty array!!!

Comment: _"it says x is not defined"_ - Do you mean the console shows `undefined`, or are you get an actual error "x is not defined"?

Comment: ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: i have declared the the two x & y variables before the get.JSON request but now when i console.log(x) it gives me undefined

Comment: Your last two comments don't agree with each other. Are you getting a ReferenceError, or getting `undefined`? Where exactly are you adding the `console.log(x)` statement?

Comment: Is that a joke? In which part of your code are you adding `console.log(x)`? That is, tell me specifically the line of code from your question above that is right before where you add `console.log(x)`.

Comment: sorry..! am putting it after the function location(x,y){loc.push({latitude:x,longitude:y});} console.log(x);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15119/discussion-between-anjelos-and-nnnnnn)